# UITableView and UIGestureRecogniser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITableView with normal vertical scrolling.

I want to add a UISwipeGestureRecnogiser to it (or somewhere connected in the view hierarchy).

I've done this, but the vertical tolerance on my gesture recogniser is pretty small. So I have to get my horizontal swipe pretty straight, otherwise the UITableView takes over and scrolls vertically. This is pretty annoying for the user.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to better handle this? Maybe putting a UIView on top of my table view that handles the gesture, but if it fails - somehow pass the event to my table View.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended creating my own gesture recogniser - following the example from the event handling guide for iOS.

I had more control over vertical tolerance using the old touchesMove and touchesBegan.

It still wasn't perfect, but it was a lot better and after testing on a few people, I could see there the swiping was less error prone.